# Monitor volume level when using headphones

Tags: ios

I'm looking to create an iphone app to help people monitor whether they are experiencing hearing loss from turning up the sound too high on their earbuds for a research project.

To do this, I want to periodically poll the volume level when music is playing on the iphone and the headphones are plugged in.

I did find the following answers that indicate it is possible however I am not familiar with iphone development.

checking when the audio is playing on the phone
[Can my app be notified when another application starts/stops playing audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113377/can-my-app-be-notified-when-another-application-starts-stops-playing-audio)

check if headphones are plugged in
[Are headphones plugged in? iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292586/are-headphones-plugged-in-ios7?rq=1#)

checking the volume level on the phone
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29170927/1361960

Comment: The three resources you provided are a good place to start with working against your requirements for the project. Is there something more specific that you're looking for help with?

Comment: @KevinAleman Actually yes. I was told by a number of people that you can't do this sort of monitoring in the background and so I just want to see if that is the case, or if there are workarounds for this. This would have to be a background process since people will use other devices to play the audio (Youtube, Spotify, etc)

Answer (score 0):

In Apple-way you cannot make app be notified when another application starts/stops playing audio.

Since the background execution of your app was limited according to the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Your code will only be executed when your application was running.